# How to add sub menu to Android action bar sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have done a action menu bar using action bar sherlock library. How i can add sub menus on each menu. When clicking a menu it will open a list of menus.

here is my code

```
            // First Menu Button
    menu.add("Help").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.HelpButtonClickListener)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.help_button)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


    // Second Menu Button
    menu.add("Like").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.LikeButtonClickListener)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.like_button)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    // Third Menu Button
    menu.add("Exit").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.ExitButtonClickListener)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    // Fourth Menu Button
    menu.add("Tab1").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.Tab1ButtonClickListener)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

The addSubMenu method returns a SubMenu object. A SubMenu is also a Menu, so you can call add on it to add items to the submenu rather than the parent menu. Your code above is creating two different submenus for Form 1 and Form 2 rather than two items within a single New Form submenu.

Find full details in this thread:
[How to add submenu items to ActionBar action in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344160/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-actionbar-action-in-code)