# Change ActionBarSherlock Home icon and show submenu on home

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I I have created a ActionBar using ActionBarSherlock. I want to display the three horizontal lines for the home option instead of the back arrow.

If I change it to :-

```
  getSupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_dark);
```

Then the desired icon is shown but the app icon does not show. Also I want to display a dropdown option when the Home option is clicked.

I tried doing the dropdown by using a spinner and applying it to:-

```
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(spinner);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

But the `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(spinner);` does not take the spinner and throws the error that I need to pass a int value to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344160/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-actionbar-action-in-code It may help you

Comment: shylendra. I have seen that already. I want to implement it on the home button