# Android ActionBar menu with vertical (rotated) text items based on Custom Action Provider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, vertical-text

I am adding a menu to an action bar item. The menu will contain vertical text for each item. What the menu contains is not important. I basically just want to create my own view that will pop up when I press an action bar item. So for the purposes of this question, you could imagine my view as a big black box.

[image]

The image on the right was made with Gimp. It is what I am trying to do, not what I have accomplished yet.

### What I have tried

In order to update an old app with the Material Design theme, I've been going through all the [lessons in the Android documentation for adding the app bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html). Since my vertical text menu doesn't fit the common cases, I have to make a custom Action Provider. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ActionProvider.html) does not provide a full example for a custom action provider, though. The best I could find was [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178683/3681880).

The best I have been able to do (with a black View representing my future menu) is shown in the following image:

[image]

The star in the image above currently has the action provider. However, the custom view gets clipped off within the action bar. How do I make it float over everything? Also, I don't want it appearing until I click on the action bar item. Currently, though, it just shows right away.

### Code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // setup toolbar
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        ...
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                return true;

            case R.id.action_favorite:
                // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
                // as a favorite...
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

...
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_favorites"
        app:actionProviderClass="com.example.chimee.MyActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

MyActionProvider.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActionProvider extends ActionProvider {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mContext = context;
    }

    // for versions older than api 16
    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView() {
        // Inflate the action provider to be shown on the action bar.
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View providerView =
                layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_action_provider, null);
        View myView =
                (View) providerView.findViewById(R.id.blackView);
        myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("myTag", "black view was clicked");
            }
        });
        return providerView;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView(MenuItem forItem) {
        // TODO: don't just repeat all this code here from above.
        // Inflate the action provider to be shown on the action bar.
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View providerView =
                layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_action_provider, null);
        View myView =
                (View) providerView.findViewById(R.id.blackView);
        myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("myTag", "black view was clicked");
            }
        });
        return providerView;
    }
}
```

my_action_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blackView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would be glad to see an example of any fully functioning custom action provider that shows a view outside of the action bar frame.

Comment: May be you need a PopUpWindow with anchor point of overflow menu icon and that Popupwindow will contain your custom component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If You didn't find Custom Action Provider based solution, may be You want use Custom [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) & [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)-based workaround which means:

1) create custom `Toolbar` with `ImageButton` as menu button and replace `ActionBar` with it (like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31477092/6950238) post of [Machado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549700/machado));

2) create `PopupWindow` with custom layout for menu items with vertical text;

3) add `onClickListener` to `ImageButton` from p.1 which show `PopupWindow` from p.2.

Layout of custom `Toolbar` (`action_bar.xml`) may be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of `MainActivity` (`activity_main.xml`) which use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="<your_package_name>.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`ImageButton` as "main popup menu" button described in `main_menu.xml` file this way (more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529346/6950238) post of [ASH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822826/ash)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_button"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert"
          android:title=""
          app:showAsAction="always"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"/>
</menu>
```

For vertical text of menu items You can use, for example, custom `View` like `VerticalLabelView` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2599518/6950238) of [kostmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105137/kostmo):

```
public class VerticalLabelView extends View {
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private String mText;
    private int mAscent;
    private Rect text_bounds = new Rect();

    final static int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 15;

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initLabelView();
    }

    public VerticalLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initLabelView();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.VerticalLabelView);

        CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_text);
        if (s != null) setText(s.toString());

        setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_textColor, 0xFF000000));

        int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.VerticalLabelView_textSize, 0);
        if (textSize > 0) setTextSize(textSize);

        a.recycle();
    }

    private final void initLabelView() {
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextSize(int size) {
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        mTextPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), text_bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension(
                measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),
                measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = text_bounds.height() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        mAscent = (int) mTextPaint.ascent();
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = text_bounds.width() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float text_horizontally_centered_origin_x = getPaddingLeft() + text_bounds.width()/2f;
        float text_horizontally_centered_origin_y = getPaddingTop() - mAscent;

        canvas.translate(text_horizontally_centered_origin_y, text_horizontally_centered_origin_x);
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        canvas.drawText(mText, 0, 0, mTextPaint);
    }
}
```

(NB: may be You need to customize paddings of `VerticalLabelView`: on line
`result = text_bounds.height() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + 16;`
add "+16" for better padding)

and `attrs.xml` for `VerticalLabelView` class:

```
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="VerticalLabelView">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Layout for `PopupWindow` (`menu_layout.xml`) in this case might be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/menu_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <<your_package_name>.VerticalLabelView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Vertical menu item 1"/>

    <<your_package_name>.VerticalLabelView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Vertical menu item 2"/>

    <<your_package_name>.VerticalLabelView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Vertical menu item 3"/>

    <<your_package_name>.VerticalLabelView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Vertical menu item 4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And `MainActivity` class can be like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private int mToolbarTitleColor;
    private ImageButton mMainMenuButton;
    private int mActionBarSize;
    private PopupWindow mPopupMenu;
    private int mTextSize = 48;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            mActionBarSize = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        mToolbarTitleColor = Color.WHITE;
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(mToolbarTitleColor);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        Drawable menuIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_more_vert);
        menuIcon.setColorFilter(mToolbarTitleColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        mMainMenuButton = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_button).getActionView();
        mMainMenuButton.setBackground(null);
        mMainMenuButton.setImageDrawable(menuIcon);
        mMainMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPopupMenu != null && mPopupMenu.isShowing()) {
                    mPopupMenu.dismiss();
                }
                mPopupMenu = createPopupMenu();
                mPopupMenu.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, mActionBarSize);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    public PopupWindow createPopupMenu() {
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);

        VerticalLabelView menuItem1 = (VerticalLabelView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item1);
        menuItem1.setOnClickListener(mOnMenuItemClickListener);
        menuItem1.setText("Vertical menu item 1");
        menuItem1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        menuItem1.setTextSize(mTextSize);

        VerticalLabelView menuItem2 = (VerticalLabelView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item2);
        menuItem2.setOnClickListener(mOnMenuItemClickListener);
        menuItem2.setText("Vertical menu item 2");
        menuItem2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        menuItem2.setTextSize(mTextSize);

        VerticalLabelView menuItem3 = (VerticalLabelView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item3);
        menuItem3.setOnClickListener(mOnMenuItemClickListener);
        menuItem3.setText("Vertical menu item 3");
        menuItem3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        menuItem3.setTextSize(mTextSize);

        VerticalLabelView menuItem4 = (VerticalLabelView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item4);
        menuItem4.setOnClickListener(mOnMenuItemClickListener);
        menuItem4.setText("Vertical menu item 4");
        menuItem4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        menuItem4.setTextSize(mTextSize);

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setContentView(popupView);

        return popupWindow;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mOnMenuItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item1: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "menu_item1");
                }
                break;
                case R.id.menu_item2: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "menu_item2");
                }
                break;
                case R.id.menu_item3: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "menu_item3");
                }
                case R.id.menu_item4: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "menu_item4");
                }
                break;
                default: {
                }
            }
            if (mPopupMenu != null && mPopupMenu.isShowing()) {
                mPopupMenu.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Ultimatly, as result You should receive something like that:

[image: Vertical menu items screenshot]

P.S. Of course You need more elegant solution for `createPopupMenu()`.